# Exchange Web services :The request failed. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I m getting this error : T**he request failed. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.**

when im trying to read email from exchange server  using EWS 
this is my code :

```
  try {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;
                ServicePointManager.MaxServicePoints =1000;
                ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 10000;
                ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = true;
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

                ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10000;

                var exchange = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);

                exchange.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user", "password", "domain");
                exchange.TraceEnabled = true;
                exchange.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;

                exchange.AutodiscoverUrl("mail-id", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
                exchange.Url = new System.Uri("https://URL/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

                exchange.KeepAlive = false;
                exchange.Timeout = 900000;
                WriteToFile("Connected to Exchange Server : " + exchange.Url.Host);

  TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, -15, 0);
                DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Add(ts);
                SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo filter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, date);

                if (exchange != null)
                {
                    FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = exchange.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, filter, new ItemView(999));


                    foreach (Item item in findResults)
                    {


                        EmailMessage message2 = EmailMessage.Bind(exchange,
                                      (EmailMessage.Bind(exchange, item.Id)).Id,
                                       new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties,
                       new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1013, MapiPropertyType.Binary)));




                        var mailbosy = message2.Body.Text;

}
```

Comment: A place to start would be to make sure your using the latest version from GitHub https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api  Other people have reported the same issue with the versions that available as a download from Microsoft or via nuGet (which is quite old now)

Comment: @Glen thanks for your comment i m using the latest version (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.2.2.0)

Comment: That isn't the latest version Microsoft stop releasing updates in 2015. The only way to get the latest is to compile the source from github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm what @Glen Scales says. The MSI download and NuGet downloads don't work. You must recompile from source.